Confused about this pharagraph:

A:「俺は大丈夫。あいつらは？」


B:「生きてはいるんじゃないでしょうか。まあ生身の人間への衝撃は推して知るべし、ですかね。とはいえそこまでもないですよ」


A: そりゃ痛そうだ。…色々とその―あるだろうが、何で気が付いたんだ？」

The character A was in danger so B came to save him, and knocked out his pursuers.

"A:「俺は大丈夫。あいつらは？」"

A says: "I'm fine. But what about the guys you knocked out?"

B:「 生きてはいるんじゃないでしょうか. まあ生身の人間への衝撃は推して知るべし、ですかね。とはいえそこまでもないですよ」

To which B replies: " "They are alive, aren't they. Well, you can easily guess the impact on the body"
This is the part where I'm lost what are they trying to imply after this?
I assume "とはいえそこまでもないですよ" Although, it's not that much (the impact) I can't make sense of the other answer: "そりゃ痛そうだ。…色々とその―あるだろうが"
"It looks like it hurt... All kinds of things are there?"

What is the question you want to ask? it seems markdown error after "This is the part where I'm lost what are they trying to imply after this?". Also I suspect that B's words would be "そこまででもないですよ", not "そこまでもないですよ".

I'm confused on what "色々とその―あるだろうが"" here could mean.

As long as I read the conversation between A and B, I feel like A changed the topic here(and the three dots represent it). So I imagine like the meaning of “色々とそのーあるだろうが、なんで気が付いたんだ？” is “Why did you notice that I’m in danger? I think there are a few clues of it though”.
